# Jest - Mocking JQuery plugin's functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have to test (using Jest) some JQuery plugins.

I'm having problems with this one, because I want to check if some function is called and it keeps telling me that it hasn't.

I simplified the plugin's structure and its something like this:

```
;(function($) {
  $.List= function() {
  
    plugin = this;
    plugin.functionA = function() {
       plugin.functionB();
    }
    
    plugin.functionB = function() {
       console.log("I'm Here")
    }

  }
}
```

When I try to test functionA through Jest, i do this:

```
it("should check if functionB is called when functionA is called", () => {
   
   const list = Manager.addList(); //we have a manager class thats responsible for adding the plugin to the page

   list.functionB = jest.fn();
   list.functionA();

   expect(list.functionB).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The words 'I'm Here' are printed in the console but Jest keeps telling me that functionB has not been called. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried spyOn functionB?

Comment: What's `Manager.addList()`?